# Swift detect touch anywhere on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, touch

I know you can detect touches using touchesBegan, touchesEnded, etc.
These all work. The only thing is that they only detect the touches on the view itself, not on anything on top of that view like a text field.

My goal is to create a timeout after a certain period of inactivity. The timeout will be reset if the screen is touched, meaning someone is still using the app. It works so far, as long as they don't tap on any controls (like a label, button, textview, etc).

I could also reset the timeout when any controls are tapped, but that would require a lot more cases (different types of controls on different view controllers).

I'm looking for and end-all screen tap detection method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add this to your AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: nil)
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        window?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        return true
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        // User tapped on screen, do whatever you want to do here.

        return false
}
```

And also make your AppDelegate conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol.

Comment: how do i make AppDelegate conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol?

Comment: Just type it in your AppDelgate class declaration like this:
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

Comment: What is the point of returning a `bool` in `gestureRecognizer()`?

Comment: @OrangePot: from the docs: Returns true (the default) to allow the gesture recognizer to examine the touch object, false to prevent the gesture recognizer from seeing this touch object.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop `UITapGestureRecognizer`, make sure the whole view is selected. It will be added on the top line of your view controller, then create an `Action` for it.

If you want to make sure that any of the buttons is not pressed, once the period of inactivity completed, add another view (can be transparent or just a bit darker) on it and connect the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it. Once tapped, release the added view and resume activity.