# Adjusting screen brightness when untouched/touched in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am quite new to `iOS` and `Swift` to please bear with be while I explain and if anything is unclear let me know and I will explain.

I have an `iOS` application, it includes some `UIImages`, `UIButtons`, etc.. and they interact when touched.

I would like to dim the screen when the application has not been touched (anywhere on the screen) for a while (lets say 10 seconds), and then as soon as a touch is detected anywhere on the `UIScreen` I would like to increase the brightness again.

I have found that the following line can be used to adjust the screen brightness:

```
UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.5)
```

but I don't know how to detect a touch anywhere on the screen (without disturbing all the other buttons etc...), and also to combine that with a timer.

*(my app is only for a specific purpose, it will not be distributed and it runs only on a iPhone 7 device with iOS10)*

Comment: May be you can add a UITapGestureRecognizer on UIWindow

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555013/swift-detect-touch-anywhere-on-the-screen

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is an [API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest) for that purpose.

`func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?`

> Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy (including itself) that contains a specified point.
>
> This method traverses the view hierarchy by calling the point(inside:with:) method of each subview to determine which subview should receive a touch event. If point(inside:with:) returns true, then the subview’s hierarchy is similarly traversed until the frontmost view containing the specified point is found. If a view does not contain the point, its branch of the view hierarchy is ignored. You rarely need to call this method yourself, but you might override it to hide touch events from subviews.

You need to create the subclass of `UIView` or `UIWindow` in which you want to detect touches.
Then override `hitTest` function and implement required logic inside it.

**Update:**
See runnable [Xcode 8 project](https://monosnap.com/file/CSPLeTdzNz2ozTlRh6FOjFuzidVvtn) to get an idea. Run app and try to press on views and outside of them, you will see logs in debugger console with info about touched view. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a hard time undrestanding the API can you provide a simple example (no need to implement the logic)